# Android: Get data from multiple activities and process them together

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'd like to design a button for users to choose an image and an audio, and then the app creates an video with the image and audio.

I hope to implement in a way:

1. A user clicks the button
2. Launch an intent to choose a photo from the gallery.
3. After the user chooses a photo and the result returns, launch the second intent to choose an audio.
4. After the user chooses an audio, the app generates a video for them.

What would be the best way to implement them?

Is it possible to write in a way like below?

```kotlin
fun onClick() {
   getImage.launch(firstIntent)

   getAudio.launch(secondIntent)

   process(image, audio)
}
```

If not, I can still write them using separated ActivityResult callback like

```kotlin
fun process(val image: Uri, val audio: Uri) {
   ...
}

val getAudio = registerForActivityResult(...) {result ->
  val audio = getAudio(result.data)

  // get image somewhere


  process(image, audio)
}

val getImage = registerForActivityResult(...) {
  val image = getImage(result.data)

  // save image somewhere

  val intent = getAudioIntent()
  getAudio.launch(intent)
}


fun onClick() {
  val intent = getImageIntent()
  getImage.launch(intent)
}
```

One difficulty I am facing is storing the image somewhere when launching the second intent.

Answer (score 0):

The first way won't work, trying to launch 2 intents like that would at best cause one to launch, then the other on top of it, and probably cause 1 to get skipped in the backstack.  The only way to do it is to startActivityForResult, wait for the result, then launch the next activity the same way.

Comment: Thanks. How do I save the previous result (i.e. image) while calling the startActivityForResult to get audio?

Comment: Put it in a variable at the class level.